# HLK Studio - Shortening MiniFilter Test Duration Using Parallelism

Tags: driver, wdk, minifilter, kernel-mode, windows-dev-center

I've also posted the same question in [Microsoft Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/8b7e9edf-5514-43e0-9989-df432871076b/hlk-studio-shortening-minifilter-test-duration-using-parallelism?forum=whck), but is seems dead... Maybe someone here can help.

After multiple trial-and-error iterations, we finally succeeded setting up a fully automated testing environment for our MiniFilter driver, as part of our Continuous Integration system (Jenkins). This runs fine with HLK Studio installed on 1 server, with 1 additional client (Windows 10).

The entire testing cycle now takes about 7 hours to complete. We have 2 additional client computers set up, and would like to shorten the MiniFilter driver certification cycle by splitting the tests and running them on multiple, identical machines in parallel.
We can see this concept exists in the HLK Studio product ("**distributed testing**"), but for some reason, it is not available for a "Software Device" (MiniFilter in our case).

We also thought about splitting the tests manually, creating multiple HLKX files in parallel then merging them ("deep merge"), but even this is not permitted according to [HLK Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/user/merge-packages).

Now that Microsoft forces us to submit drivers for signing (or else, computers with "Secure Boot" feature will refuse to load the driver), this is becoming a mission-critical process.

Did anyone succeed in running such tests in parallel, shortening the test duration?